# dotnet core aspnet 2.2 image works on windows containers but not linux

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, docker-desktop, wsl-2

I have a project built using .net 2.2. Here is the dockerfile from one of the services:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS publish
WORKDIR /src
COPY Identity.Api.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore MyApp.Api.csproj
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.Api.dll"]
```

For my colleagues, they can pull this project and docker build using this dockerfile when running Docker Desktop using Linux Containers. But for me, for some weird reason, when I try to docker build, I get the following error

```
Step 8/14 : RUN dotnet restore MyApp.Api.csproj
 ---> Running in 99df436556bb
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.207/NuGet.targets(119,5): error : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'System.Memory.4.5.1' from source '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder'. [/src/MyApp.Api.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.207/NuGet.targets(119,5): error :   Root element is missing. [/src/MyApp.Api.csproj]
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore MyApp.Api.csproj' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Here is my dotnet --info

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.102
 Commit:    71365b4d42

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.102\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.2
  Commit:  cb5f173b96

.NET SDKs installed:
  2.1.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.520 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.107 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

However, if I switch to Windows Containers, I can get this project to docker build.

I can't figure out what is unique about my environment.

I have Docker Container running WSL2.

```
PS c:\> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: See [Remove the NuGetFallbackFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-windows#remove-the-nuget-fallback-folder) and [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/4688)

Comment: I tried that to no avail. Ultimately I figured out that when I switched to windows containers, my build worked, but not linux which is totally bizarre as these are linux images. I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling docker and that fixed it. Grrr.